# Access an selected image within a contenteditable field in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, contenteditable, getselection

I have a problem to get src or id or whatever of an selected image that is inside a contenteditable div-container within an iframe. Well, it is possible to get the selected text information with a getSelection()-call like this:

```
window.document.getElementById("monitor").contentWindow.document.getSelection();
// "monitor" = iframe id
```

But if I select an image instead of text, I just got an empty result. I searched hours and hours but didn't find any solution. Does someone knows a way how to solve this problem? (I'm using Firefox 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.getSelection()` (for which `document.getSelection()` is an alias in HTML5-compliant browsers) returns a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection) object, not a string (it only superficially appears to be a string because its `toString()` method returns the selected text). The most useful aspect for this is the ability to get one or more [DOM Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) objects representing the selection using `getRangeAt()`.

Once you have a Range, getting all the DOM nodes it contains is a little tricky. You could use my [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) library, which adds a `getNodes()` method to its implementation of Range:

```
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
if (sel.rangeCount) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var elements = range.getNodes([1]);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        alert("Selected element: " + elements[i].tagName);
    }
}
```